# Radio - add class at div when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to add addition class in JS to the div or table , when radio input is checked ?

I would like add class ***table-selected*** , to the *div class="table-item"*
when I checked a radio input .

```js
$(".table-item input").change(function() {
  var div = $(this).closest('.table-item');
  $(this).is(":checked") ? div.addClass("table-selected") : div.removeClass("table-selected");
});
```

```css
#test .table-item {
  border: solid 1px #666;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #CCC
}

#test .table-selected {
  border: 1 px solid #F00;
  background-color: #00F
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">

  <div class="table-item">
    <div><label for="check1"><input type='radio' name='rad' value='1'>1</label></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <div><label for="check2"><input type='radio' name='rad' value='2'>2</label></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <div><label for="check3"><input type='radio' name='rad' value='3'>3</label></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

But this work some wrong , add class , but it does not remove it when unchecked

Comment: You should ideally accept an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove class from other before adding to current. Triggers fire for only that element, so check will run for that element not others.
**Update Link:** https://jsfiddle.net/m637ndrx/2/

```
 $(".table-item input").change(function() {
  var div = $(this).closest('.table-item');
  $('.table-item').removeClass("table-selected")
  $(this).is(":checked") ? div.addClass("table-selected") : div.removeClass("table-selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just removing the class from the **selected** `div`. The `else` part of that ternary condition would never be satisfied because there `div` represents the button that you selected.

You need to remove the class from all the divs.

```
$(".table-item").removeClass('table-selected');
var div = $(this).closest('.table-item');
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  div.addClass("table-selected");
}
```

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/g5o2w47v/

Comment: This works the same as OP's code. What did you solve?

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong jsfiddle link. Just updated with the correct link.